# Вызов двух методов класса последовательно

Tags: php

Хотелось бы узнать как в классе реализовать методы, чтобы они вызывались примерно так:

```
$class = new ClassName();
$str = $class->str('string')->upp();
```

В данном случае реализация функции upp должно быть просто `strtoupper($string)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно что бы метод возвращал объект .

```
public function setParam(array $queryParam)
{
   $queryKeys = array_keys($queryParam);
   $this->queryParam = array_fill_keys($queryKeys, "");
   //возвращаем текущий объект
   return $this;
}
```

Comment: Еще можно дополнить - называется этот подход "Цепочка вызовов"

Comment: Еще можно дополнить - называется этот подход "Текучий интерфейс" (Fluent Interface)